# can i generate java class from xml using java program?

Tags: java

Actually I have tried this with XMLSchema using configuration. Now I want to create a Java class using XML file by Java program. Help me out.

https://sanaulla.info/2013/01/25/using-jaxb-to-generate-java-objects-from-xml-document/

I used this link get generate my Java class by using XMLSchema.

Answer (score 0):

There's a library called XStream, which is used for specifically this purpose (XML to java or vice versa).

Alternate Soluton - JAXB.

Sample program using XStream -

```
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias;

public class ConverterExample3 {
    static String xml1 = "<Music><type>rock</type></Music>";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        XStream xStream = new XStream();
        xStream.processAnnotations(Music.class);
        Music musicObject = (Music) xStream.fromXML(xml1);
        System.out.println(musicObject);
        // prints Music [type=ROCK]
    }

}

@XStreamAlias("Music")
class Music {
    public enum genre {
        ROCK, JAZZ
    };

    genre type;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Music [type=" + type + "]";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JAXB for converting Java Class to XML and vice versa.

Tutorial for the same is given here:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/xml/javax_xml_bind_jaxb.htm

Answer (score 0):

you can covert the java object to xml(marshalling) and xml to java object(unmarshalling) with jaxb
you can go through this link for example[http://www.javatpoint.com/jaxb-unmarshalling-example]